# Does these have same meanings: "I was born" and "my birth"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

"I was told years after I was born that..."
"I was told years after my birth that..."

What should I use? Which is correct?

Comment: Both are [a-okay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-ok).

Comment: Agree, both are fine, "years after I was born" is slightly less formal than "years after my birth" and would probably be more common in natural speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I was born = after my birth.  They mean the same thing.  Though the former is in in the passive, it's much more common to use was/were born.

The phrase "after my birth" fits better  in formal English.